# Force Google Chrome's "send to device" to send original URL not canonical URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a web page that has a canonical URL in metadata but page URL itself is different from the canonical link. (always)
The problem is when the user tries to send this page to another device using google chrome's send-to-device ability, chrome will send the canonical URL, not the current page's original URL.

I'm looking for a solution that let me force google to send the original URL not the canonical URL.

Comment: I’m guessing they are probably sending the canonical URL on purpose. Not sure if you can change anything about that. _“canonical URL in metadata but page URL itself is different from the canonical link. (always)”_ - and why is that the case? Might make more sense perhaps then, to not set canonical to begin with? If you need it for SEO purposes(?), then maybe you could have the server deliver it, but then remove the link element via JS on the client side (and hope that makes Chrome send the actual URL then)?

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense. I deliver it in HTML but remove it in the browser using JS.